# How can i use a Jquery code to highligh a word in a select option html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can someone help me and give me a solution for this question: I want to highlight a single word in a select option html element with jquery. For example:

```
 <select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">not Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">but Audi</option>
</select>
```

The word "not" should be in red and the word "but" in green (with CSS). I found the following [website](http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2012/jquery/targeting-a-specific-word-using-javascript-and-jquery/#comment-396545http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2012/jquery/targeting-a-specific-word-using-javascript-and-jquery/#comment-396545) with a code for a similar problem, but i can modified the jquery code so, that it works with the option select element. Have someone us us a solution for this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible because you would need an additional element wrapping the word "not", but `option` elements can only have **text** content.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option

It seems that at least in Chrome and Firefox you cannot even have pseudo elements inside an `option` tag:

```css
[value=saab]::before { content: "not "; }
```

```html
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">but Audi</option>
</select>
```

As it stands, jQuery cannot help you either because jQuery cannot do what the DOM cannot do.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using jQueryUI selectmenu, which replaces the native select element:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<select id="myselect">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">not Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi">but Audi</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$( function() {
    $.ui.selectmenu.prototype._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    var text = String(item.label);
    if (text.match(/not/)) {
    text = text.replace(
            new RegExp('not', 'gi'),
            '<strong style="color:red;">$&</strong>');
        }
    if (text.match(/but/)) {
    text = text.replace(
            new RegExp('but', 'gi'),
            '<strong style="color:green;">$&</strong>');
        }
    return $("<li></li>")
        .data("item.selectmenu", item)
        .append("<div>" + text + "</div>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
$( "#myselect" ).selectmenu({
    width: 150
    });
});
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/happy_ant/pen/KLXyeE

Comment: It works: https://codepen.io/happy_ant/pen/KLXyeE . You have to include jQuery library, jQueryUI library and jQueryUI CSS for this to work (as shown in HTML of my codepen demo).